# varchar is not assigned to variable in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Varchar value not assign to variable, but others from questions are assigned.

```
$this->db->where('ua_u_id', $row->u_id);
$this->db->where('ua_tq_id', $row2->tq_id);
$query3 = $this->db->get('user_answers');

$data['question-data'] = $query3->result();
echo '<p class="card-text">'.$data['question-data'][0]->ua_answer_text.'</p>';
log_message('debug', 'editTestView: $questionData = '.$data['question-data'][0]->ua_answer_text.', num_rows: '.$query3->num_rows().', question id: '.$data['question-data'][0]->ua_id);
```

debug message returns ID, but not text - "ua_answer_text" is correct name of column in table and is not empty.

Comment: what's the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($data['question-data']);`? Add it after `$data['question-data'] = $query3->result();` and show us it's output

Comment: use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` (it's not intended to use in debugging, has some weird behaviours)